# time related functions and multiple threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, time

I'm working on Linux (CentOS 6.3 distribution with libc-2.12.so).

I wonder if the C library function `time()`, `localtime()`, `mktime()` could be used under multiple thread environment.

Just for an example (not necessarily my project code):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

  time_t timep;

  struct tm *p;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    time(&timep);
    printf("time() : %d \n", timep);
    p = localtime(&timep);
    timep = mktime(p);

    printf("time()->localtime()->mktime():%d\n", timep);
  }

  return 0;    
}
```

What if I wrapper the above code with OpenMP? that is to put it under multiple threaded environment.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{

  time_t timep;

  struct tm *p;

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    time(&timep);
    printf("time() : %d \n", timep);
    p = localtime(&timep);
    timep = mktime(p);

    printf("time()->localtime()->mktime():%d\n", timep);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "/n" is *not* the same as "\n".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localtime` is not thread safe, from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.23.3` *Time conversion functions* says:

> Except for the strftime function, these functions each return a pointer to one of two
>   types of static objects: a broken-down time structure or an array of char. Execution of
>   any of the functions that return a pointer to one of **these object types may overwrite the
>   information in any object of the same type pointed to by the value returned from any
>   previous call to any of them. The implementation shall behave as if no other library
>   functions call these functions**.

`localtime` comes under section `7.23.3.4` and falls under that condition. The [man page for localtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) also clearly states it is not thread safe:

> The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to  static data and hence **are not thread-safe**. Thread-safe versions asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r() and localtime_r() are specified by SUSv2, and available since libc 5.2.5

Neither `time` nor `mktime` have similar conditions attached to them in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

From [manual localtime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime):

> The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe. Thread-safe versions asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r() and localtime_r() are specified by SUSv2, and available since libc 5.2.5.