# Is standard C mktime thread safe on linux?

Tags: c, linux, thread-safety

The man page of mktime didn't mention thread safety of mktime, but it did mention this which make it look like thread **unsafe**:

> Calling mktime() also  sets  the  external variable  tzname  with information about the current time zone.

I know on Linux mktime calls tzset to set tzname, which is a char*[]:

> extern char *tzname[2];

and tzset will read environment variable TZ and file /etc/localtime. So unless mktime uses a mutex to protect all these operations, I can't see how it can be thread safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C time function multiple thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348383/c-time-function-multiple-thread)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The previous question and its answers concentrate on `asctime`, `ctime`, `gmtime` and `localtime` which return pointers to static data and are therefore thread-unsafe by design. This question is specifically about `mktime` whose interface is not thread-unsafe, but the side effect additionally mandated by POSIX could be. Therefore this is not a duplicate of the previous question.

Comment: that's right, I think the first two lines added are a bit misleading, the previous question didn't answer anything regarding mktime.

Comment: @user4815162342 If the C standard and POSIX conflict then the [C standard wins](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377007/1708801). The C standard indicates `mktime` is thread safe as my answer to the question I indicated as a dup explains at the end.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour C99 doesn't indicate that `mktime` is thread-safe because threads are not part of C99 - what it does state is that subsequent calls won't overrun the result of previous ones (or, more precisely, it fails to state that such a thing could happen). POSIX `mktime` includes additional functionality which does not conflict with the one in C99, so the "in case of conflict, C wins" rule doesn't apply. Again, it is quite reasonable to ask whether the functionality added by POSIX is thread-safe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's true that `mktime` has a side effect, but the side effect should be harmless in most programs.

According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html), the side effect will be as if [tzset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tzset.html) has been called, which in turn merely copies the timezone information from the `TZ` environment variable to the `tzname` array of C strings. If your application doesn't change `TZ`, you will have no problem with calling `mktime()` concurrently.

In addition to this, GNU libc's `tzset` [does use a mutex](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blame;f=time/tzset.c;hb=26b4d7667169f8db26fd8194b3c498ec58e50f90#l570) to protect the integrity of `tzname`. This is a quality-of-implementation addition not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: well, but it looks TZ can be changed by many other time functions, eg. strftime, or by calling tzset directly. Also TZ usually points to a file which is symlinked from /etc/localtime, which can be changed at any time as well?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your edit, this makes more sense, the whole tzset call is protected by a mutex, so any time function using timezone information will be synchronized at the mutex, including strptime and strftime. This does guarantees thread safety, but sounds very inefficient to me.

Comment: @swang `tzset` has a [fast path](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blame;f=time/tzset.c;hb=26b4d7667169f8db26fd8194b3c498ec58e50f90#l173) that bails out if the value of the `TZ` environment variable hasn't changed, changes to `/etc/localtime` notwithstanding. Because of that its efficiency should be reasonable.

Comment: you are right, but the inefficiency still exists because of the mutex, if I have multiple threads calling different time functions I'm introducing a implicit synchronizing point. I did strace on my application and indeed see __lll_lock_wait_private() from threads using strftime, presumably because one thread calling mktime is doing tzset_internal().

Comment: @swang In my experience the libc time functions are not written for high efficiency, so my intuition would be that a mutex (especially when uncontested, in which case it stays in user space) would not introduce a measurable slowdown. But I have zero data to support that hunch, and I haven't studied the implementation of glibc private locks.